# C/C++ ffmpeg output is low quality and blurry

Tags: c++, c, video, ffmpeg, resolution

I've made a program that takes a video file as input, edits it using opengl/glfw, then encodes that edited video. The program works just fine, I get the desired output. However  the video quality is really low and I don't know how to adjust it. The editing seems fine, since the display on the glfw window is high resolution. I don'T think its about scaling since it just reads the pixels on the glfw window and passes it to the encoder, and the glfw window is high res.

Here is what the glfw window looks like when the program is running:

[image]

I'm encoding in YUV420P formatting, but the information I'm getting from the glfw window is in RGBA format. I'm getting the data using:

```cpp
   glReadPixels(0, 0,
   gl_width, gl_height, 
   GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
   (GLvoid*) state.glBuffer
);
```

I simply got the [muxing.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/muxing.c) example from ffmpeg's docs and edited it slightly so it looks something like this:

```cpp
AVFrame* video_encoder::get_video_frame(OutputStream *ost)
{
    AVCodecContext *c = ost->enc;

    /* check if we want to generate more frames */
    if (av_compare_ts(ost->next_pts, c->time_base,
                      (float) STREAM_DURATION / 1000, (AVRational){ 1, 1 }) > 0)
        return NULL;

    /* when we pass a frame to the encoder, it may keep a reference to it
     * internally; make sure we do not overwrite it here */
    if (av_frame_make_writable(ost->frame) < 0)
        exit(1);

        
    if (c->pix_fmt != AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P) {           
        /* as we only generate a YUV420P picture, we must convert it
         * to the codec pixel format if needed */
        if (!ost->sws_ctx) {
            ost->sws_ctx = sws_getContext(c->width, c->height,
                                          AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
                                          c->width, c->height,
                                          c->pix_fmt,
                                          SCALE_FLAGS, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            if (!ost->sws_ctx) {
                fprintf(stderr,
                        "Could not initialize the conversion context\n");
                exit(1);
            } 
        }
    #if __AUDIO_ONLY
        image_for_audio_only(ost->tmp_frame, ost->next_pts, c->width, c->height);
    #endif

        sws_scale(ost->sws_ctx, (const uint8_t * const *) ost->tmp_frame->data,
                  ost->tmp_frame->linesize, 0, c->height, ost->frame->data,
                  ost->frame->linesize);
    } else {
        //This is where I set the information I got from the glfw window.
        set_frame_yuv_from_rgb(ost->frame, ost->sws_ctx);
    }
    ost->frame->pts = ost->next_pts++;

    return ost->frame;
}

void video_encoder::set_frame_yuv_from_rgb(AVFrame *frame, struct SwsContext *sws_context) {
    const int in_linesize[1] = { 4 * width };
    //uint8_t* dest[4] = { rgb_data, NULL, NULL, NULL };
    sws_context = sws_getContext(
            width, height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGBA,
            width, height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
            SWS_BICUBIC, 0, 0, 0);

    sws_scale(sws_context, (const uint8_t * const *)&rgb_data, in_linesize, 0,
            height, frame->data, frame->linesize);
}
```

`rgb_data` is the buffer I got from the glfw window. It's simply an `uint8_t*`.

And at the end of all this, here is what the encoded output looks like when ran through mplayer:

[image]

It's much lower quality compare to the glfw window. How can I improve the quality of the video?

Comment: I don't use the C version of FFmpeg but on the command line version, I had to **provide output twice** (unique file names) to avoid my frames having the blurry/blocky pixels. You can try maybe running your **write frame** function twice for every one frame you send out to it. Or try providing a second output filename to write to and see if you end up with two output files (a blurry and clear one)... PS: On command line I was sending frames from my app into FFmpeg via **standard input/output**.

Comment: @VC.One Sending frames twice will cause the timing to be faulty and mess everything up, but I might try giving off 2 outputs.

Comment: _"Sending frames twice will cause the timing to be faulty"_ is a logical thought but I can't confirm what FFmpeg is doing exactly under the hood. Think of sending frame twice as writing an interlaced picture (you send first to provide top order, then secondly to provide lower order, but the 2 sent will make 1 final clear image). Don't assume it will mess time, it might fix pixel structure. Just test and I hope something works for you.

Comment: At a guess you're resizing the images to some smaller size (or possibly just a slightly different size). You're also subsampling to 4:2:0 so the image quality will be poorer than the original. It looks like you're applying some compression too, you might want to use a higher quality/bit rate with your encoder. Please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles Opengl handles all of the drawing, video is resized, yes but opengl uses textures, vertex shaders and fragment shaders to propperly draw it, so the data I pass onto the encoder, on paper, should be fine. The problem is at the settings/formatting. Higher bit_rate/quality might fix my problem. I can add more code however the code orginally is really long.

Answer (score 0):

Here are encoding settings from youtube for a better quality:

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171

Make sure to have high bitrate and gop size. E.g. 5Mbps and 60 correspondingly.